# blue_thermal_printer works through USB developper mode but not when running signed APK

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-bluetooth

I flutter run this code with USB connected:

```
class PrinterService extends GetxService {
  late BlueThermalPrinter bluetooth;
  Rx<BluetoothDevice?> selectedPrinter = Rx(null);
  RxBool connected = RxBool(false);
  TestPrint testPrint = TestPrint();
  RxList<BluetoothDevice> printerDevicesList = RxList();
  var logger = Logger(
    output: FileOutput(),
  );

  @override
  void onInit() {
    start();
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  bool initialized = false;
  Future<void> start() async {
    try {
      bluetooth = BlueThermalPrinter.instance;
      print("====================Bluetooth Instance: ${bluetooth}");
      bluetooth.disconnect();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    if (initialized == false) {
      print("====================initialized is: ${initialized}");
      initialized = true;
      initPlatformState();
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      if (printerDevicesList.isNotEmpty) {
        selectedPrinter.value = printerDevicesList
            .firstWhere((element) => element?.name == 'TM-m30-b001');
        print("============= {${selectedPrinter.value!.name}}");
        connect();
      } else {
        print("============= {No Printer Found}");
      }
    }
  }

  String storageKeyForPrinter = 'selected_printer';

  Future<void> connect() async {
    if (selectedPrinter.value != null) {
      listenToState();
      if (connected.value == false) {
        try {
          showLoadingIndicator('Connecting to Printer');
          await bluetooth.connect(selectedPrinter.value!);
          print("============= ${selectedPrinter.value!.name}");
        } catch (e) {
          // showErrorIndicator(error: 'Error printer connection. Please try again later...');
        }
      }
    }
  }

  Future show(
    String message, {
    Duration duration = const Duration(seconds: 3),
  }) async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(Get.context!).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text(
          message,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        duration: duration,
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> disconnect() async {
    await bluetooth.disconnect();
    connected.value = false;
  }

  Future<void> listenToState() async {
    connected.value = selectedPrinter.value?.connected ?? false;
    bluetooth.isDeviceConnected(selectedPrinter.value!).asStream().listen(
      (event) {
        connected.value = event ?? false;
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    bool? isConnected = await bluetooth.isConnected;
    print("===================In InitPlatformState");
    List<BluetoothDevice> devices = [];
    try {
      devices = await bluetooth.getBondedDevices();
    } on PlatformException {}

    //   print(devices);
    printerDevicesList.value = devices;
    print("====================printerDevicesList: $devices");

    if (isConnected == true) {
      connected.value = true;
    }
  }
}
```

When in signed apk, I see no device (in my setting widget)

```
...
     if (controller.printerDevicesList.isEmpty)
         const Center(
           child: Text(
             'No Printer found. Please try again.',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
           ),
         ),
...
```

What are the differences when running this in flutter run vs. the signed Android apk?

What is a good way to observe internal variable when running the signed APK^?

The rest of the program works perfectly, only the blutooth subsystem.

I tried running changing various settings, notably adding

```
  buildTypes {
    release {
        ... 
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled false
    }
 }
```

In gradle.build